# Details about /proc/$pid/attr?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am looking at files under /prod/$pid/attr

> > > current  exec  fscreate  keycreate  prev  sockcreate

anybody know what do these files do ?

Comment: [man proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Answer (score 2):

Proc = process information for pseudofilesystem

/proc/[pid]/attr = Security attributes

/exec = represents the attributes assigned to the process / this is needed to support role/domain transitions

/fscreate = represents the attributes to assign files created by subsequent calls - mkdir - symlink

/keycreate = if/when a process writes a security context into this file all previous keys will be labelled with this context

/prev = shows previous values /proc/[PID]/attr/current

/sockcreate = if/when a process writes security context into this file all the previously created sockets will be labelled with this context